# How to shorten WHERE clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, view, where-clause

I am writing the below view in SQL Server 2019 for my database and it works fine. I feel my `WHERE` clause is too long and maybe a shorter clause you write would satisfy my needs. Also `WHERE` clause filters the view well. It seems too novice so any advanced solution is appreciated.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View1 
AS 
    SELECT
        Table1.QNO,
        Table1.QRevNO,
        Table1.QID,
        Table1.LStatus AS Status,
        Table1.StatusCode AS [Status Code],
        CASE
            WHEN Table1.IsProject = 1 THEN 'Goods'
            WHEN Table1.IsProject = 2 THEN 'Services'
            ELSE 'Project'
        END AS [Product Type],
        Table2.ProductGroup AS [Group],
        Table2.TotalOfItem AS [Sales],
        Table3.CompanyName AS [Customer]
    FROM 
        dbo.Table1
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Table2 ON Table1.QID = Table2.QID
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Table3 ON Table3.CompanyID = Table1.CompanyID
    WHERE 
        Table1.RevActivated = 1
        AND ((DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.ORDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
             OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.PIDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
        AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL)
             OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.PODate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
        AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL
        AND Table1.PIDate IS NULL)
    OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.BADate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
      AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PIDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PODate IS NULL)
    OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.OCDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
      AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PIDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PODate IS NULL
      AND Table1.BADate IS NULL)
    OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.ShipDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
      AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PIDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PODate IS NULL
      AND Table1.BADate IS NULL
      AND Table1.OCDate IS NULL)
    OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.INVDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
      AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PIDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PODate IS NULL
      AND Table1.BADate IS NULL
      AND Table1.OCDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.ShipDate IS NULL)
    OR (DATEPART(YEAR, Table1.PDDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
      AND Table1.ORDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PIDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.PODate IS NULL
      AND Table1.BADate IS NULL
      AND Table1.OCDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.ShipDate IS NULL
      AND Table1.INVDate IS NULL)))
GO
```

Comment: Seems like you have a denormalization problem: you shouldn't have seven similar columns of dates, instead you want a separate table of events (foreign-keyed to `Table1`), then you can do a simple join or `exists`

Comment: FYI, using things like `DATEPART` on your columns in the `WHERE` will cause your query to be non-SARGable, which will cause poorer performance. Instead of checking the year, check the date is in a date range that includes the entirety of the year. For example `>= '2021-01-01'` and `< '2022-01'01'`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, more compact code isn't necessarily a better one. Although the following is probably a bit easier to read:

```sql
...
WHERE t1.RevActivated = 1
  and coalesce(
    t1.ORDate,
    t1.PIDate,
    t1.PODate,
    t1.BADate,
    t1.OCDate,
    t1.ShipDate,
    t1.INVDate,
    t1.PDDate
  ) >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1)
  and coalesce(
    t1.ORDate,
    t1.PIDate,
    t1.PODate,
    t1.BADate,
    t1.OCDate,
    t1.ShipDate,
    t1.INVDate,
    t1.PDDate
  ) < datefromparts(year(getdate()) + 1, 1, 1);
```

where `t1` is an [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) for the `dbo.Table1` table.

To make this mess run sufficiently fast even after the size of your table will exceed the amount of rows supported by Excel spreadsheets, well, that's not easy. You can try an index that includes all 8 of these `XyzDate` columns, in exactly the same order your code prioritises them. A better approach would be to normalise your data model and not work with pivoted sources (unless, of course, this isn't a DWH already).